# Strange shadows appearing in my eevee render

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shadows

I am just starting in blender doing some animations rendered with eevee, I already tried everything to remove some strange shadows(artefacts) in some models but had no success.
The top image is the camera view before rendering, the way that I need, the second is the render.
Maybe someone had the same problem, I am using the latest version.
Thank you so much!
[image]
[file:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k3h3CFWqhENEaRXpmvefA_zp5RJM5vQb/view?usp=sharing) [3d file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k3h3CFWqhENEaRXpmvefA_zp5RJM5vQb/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please add a circle or some arrows to show what you mean. And if we should help you - also provide your blend file so can !

Comment: Sorry about that, =) just updated the post

Comment: thank you. Now i did understand what you mean. But...please add the blend file in that way, that if we press F12, we see your result as you posted us the screenshot. I don't want to search which frame i have to take and i also would love to see the table if i open it and not have to search for it. Thank you!

Comment: Please don't make your questions depend exclusively on others 
downloading the file, or reading links, just to understanding the 
issue. Please use the [edit] option at the bottom of your question 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how 
you set up your project.
[Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)
that might help others understand your scene and settings.

Comment: maybe try to enable/disable the Shadow and Contact Shadows option of your lights?

Comment: Hey @moonboots, thank you, yes, If I disable one of the shadows the problem is gone, and the shadows as well hahaha, I really think that is an eevee limitation because if I use cycles the problem is gone, but the time is way bigger.

Comment: Hey @Emir, thank you, I just updated the image =)

Comment: Hey @Chris, just updated the file, if you press F12 now it should work. Thank you for the feedback.